# AWS: Number of lambda invocations in metrics not corresponding with actual number of invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

Good day all,

Below is a snippet of my lambda invocation code with `boto3`:

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='eu-west-1')
json_payload = json.dumps(data)
lambda_response = lambda_client.invoke(target_lambda_arn, 'RequestResponse', json_payload)
```

In my opinion this should only invoke 1 lambda, since it is 1 call, but if I look at the lambda metrics, it shows a total of 4 invocations at the time when the call was made with above snippet. If I do 2 calls, then it shows a total of 16 invocations. Why does this happen? Shouldn't it correspond on both sides?

Note: The above snippet is in an AWS Glue EDL script running on 2 worker nodes and G.1x worker type, with no retries set on the job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the Lambda function is failing and is causing a retry? For more information you can have a look at this resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html If you'd prefer to disable that feature you can do so by accessing your Lambda function and set the Retry Attempts to 0. You can find this configuration on the Configuration -> Asynchronous Invocation tab. You can also have a look at Cloudwatch Logs and Metrics to gain a deeper understanding of the underlying root cause.